# styling using scss on nextjs not working with .active

Tags: sass, next.js

im learning next js, im using scss for styling. as image 2 show the style work fine but not when with .active class
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It works fine you need to use `:` not `.`

```
&:active {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```